# How can I make a recursion back-track over itself?

Tags: java, user-interface, recursion, maze

I'm having an issue and I'm not certain if it's recursion-based. I created a GUI maze that solves itself but the curser jumps over any recursion-traveled square instead of re-traveling the square. Even though it ultimately finds the goal, I want to show it's entire path but I can't stop the curser from jumping around.

I'm using Runnable to track the maze in real-time so I can see it bounce but without the recursion-travel keeping it bound, the recursive functions cease to work (it just bounces back and forth which, again, I don't quite understand.) I started java about three months ago in an accelerated program so I'm not sure if the issue is my understanding of recursion, or a simple addition to a method, or if I'll have to rewrite a large portion of code.

I included the whole code just in case but really it's an issue that's within the travel method or the visited method. Would the answer be to write an entirely new method that re-travels the changed "visited" string maze? I've been struggling with this for a bit and I just need some direction toward an answer.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class extraCreditMaze extends JPanel implements Runnable {        //uses Runnable to execute jPanel

   private String [][] ratMaze =                         //string maze
   {{"blocked","blocked","blocked","blocked","blocked","blocked","blocked","blocked"},
    {"blocked","open","blocked","blocked","blocked","blocked","blocked","blocked"},
    {"blocked","open","open","open","open","open","open","blocked"},
    {"blocked","blocked","open","blocked","open","blocked","open","blocked"},
    {"blocked","blocked","open","blocked","open","blocked","open","goal"},
    {"blocked","open","open","open","blocked","open","open","blocked"},
    {"blocked","blocked","blocked","open","open","open","blocked","blocked"},
    {"blocked","blocked","blocked","blocked","blocked","blocked","blocked","blocked"}};

   final private int SquareSize = 15;
   final private int BoardSize = 17;
   private boolean free = false;
   int axisX = 1, axisY = 1;

   public void paintComponent(Graphics color)            //paint components for char
   {
      super.paintComponent(color);
        for(int row = 0;  row < ratMaze.length; row++)
      {
         for(int col = 0; col< ratMaze.length; col++)
         {
            if(row==axisX && col==axisY)                 //traveling curser = blue
            {
               color.setColor(Color.blue);
               color.fillOval(col*15,row*15,15,15);
                }
            else if(ratMaze[row][col]=="blocked")              //empty = black
            {
               color.setColor(Color.black);
               color.fillRect(col*SquareSize,row*SquareSize,BoardSize,BoardSize);
            }
           else if(ratMaze[row][col]=="goal")
            {
               color.setColor(Color.red);               //goal = red
               color.fillOval(col*15,row*15,15,15);
            }
            else if(ratMaze[row][col]=="visited")
            {
               color.setColor(Color.green);              //path traveled = green
               color.fillOval(col*15,row*15,15,15);
            }
            else
            {
                color.setColor(Color.white);              //empty space = white
                color.fillRect(col*SquareSize,row*SquareSize,BoardSize,BoardSize);
            }
        }
      }
   }

   public void run ()                                    //starts run at (1,1)
   {
      travel(1,1);
   }

   public boolean goal(int x, int y){                    //method to check goal (true/false)
        if(ratMaze[x][y]=="goal")
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
   }

   public void changedVisited(int x, int y)              //method to change traveled
   {
            ratMaze[x][y] = "visited";
            axisX = x;
            axisY = y;
   }

   public boolean boundaries(int x, int y)               //check boundaries
   {
        if(ratMaze[x][y]=="blocked")
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
   }

   public boolean visited(int x, int y)                  //check if visited
   {
        if(ratMaze[x][y]=="visited")
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
   }

   private void travel(int x, int y)
   {
      if(boundaries(x,y))                                //makes sure it's within bounds
         return;

      if(visited(x,y))                                   //makes sure it hasn't already been visited
         return;

      if(goal(x,y))                                      //checks if it's the goal/changes boolean
      {
         free = true;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You did it, Dr. Cui!");      //fun message!
      }

      if(!free)                                           //all recursion functions if free=false
      {
        changedVisited(x,y);                             //changes traveled block to "visited"
        repaint();                                       //repaints visited
        try {Thread.sleep(300); } catch (Exception e) { }//slows down the traveling curser
                                                          //I do not understand catch (Exception e)

            travel(x-1,y);                                 //recursive travel functions
            travel(x+1,y);
            travel(x,y-1);
            travel(x,y+1);
        }       
   }
}

public class runExtraCreditMaze {
   public static void main (String [] args) {       //JFrame panel and perimeters
      JFrame output = new JFrame();
      output.setSize(115, 150);
      output.setTitle("The Rat Maze");
      output.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      extraCreditMaze Maze = new extraCreditMaze();
      output.setContentPane(Maze);
      output.setVisible(true);

      Thread runnable = new Thread(Maze);           //Creates Runnable thread for Maze object
      runnable.start();                             //Starts Runnable thread of Maze object
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn about `enum`, instead of using string literals for that, as your code is currently very prone to errors.

Comment: Using == on strings is questionable.  They might work, or they might not.  Try "a"+"b" == "ab", it'll probably result in a false.  yours MAY work because the compiler tends to combine string constants but the behavior is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, as you wrote with the "visited". You are missing an decision tree on what to do, when there is no valid move and you are not in the goal. You will need to allow your rat to back track itself. You will probably need to "free" the visited cells when returning from no valid move.
I will try to add some code samples when I get to IDE :)

update: this is very badly written, and it is a bit lagging. but it should work. It needs a bit of cleaning and verification... I reused your boolean variable, which is bad .. :) and switched the true/false. I will do a bit of cleaning up tomorrow just to leave a nicer answer, but I think you will manage to understand what is going on.

update2:I have cleaned it a bit. Important lessons here are as follows:

1) backtracking needs to be done when all 4 steps fails. When your rat have nowhere to go, you need to disqualify the cell from your shortest path (ratMaze[x][y]="open")
2) You need to change position of your rat, when you return from recursion call, but before you continue with next step into. You will also need to let your program know that you are returning from recursion (thus the isBacktracking)

```
private void repaintMaze(int x, int y) {
  changedVisited(x, y); //changes traveled block to "visited"
  repaint(); //repaints visited
  isBacktracking = false;
  try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
}

private boolean travel(int x, int y) {
  if (goal(x, y)) //checks if it's the goal/changes boolean
  {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You did it, Dr. Cui!");//fun message!
      return true;
  }

  if (boundaries(x, y) || visited(x, y))  //makes sure it's within bounds
        return false;

  repaintMaze(x, y);
  boolean result; //recursive travel functions
  result = travel(x - 1, y);
  if (result) {
      return true;
  }
  if (isBacktracking) {
      repaintMaze(x, y);
  }
  result = travel(x + 1, y);
  if (result) {
      return true;
  }
  if (isBacktracking) {
      repaintMaze(x, y);
  }
  result = travel(x, y - 1);
  if (result) {
      return true;
  }
  if (isBacktracking) {
      repaintMaze(x, y);
  }
  result = travel(x, y + 1);
  if (result) {
      return true;
  }
  if (isBacktracking) {
      repaintMaze(x, y);
  }

  ratMaze[x][y] = "open";
  isBacktracking = true;
  return false;
}
```

you should also add exit on close to your JFrame :) It will stop the application once you click the X button on the window itself

```
output.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that would be awesome. I understand the concept of what you're saying but I'm still missing something. I feel like the answer is in front of me and that's it's rather simple but I'm close to finals and my brain feels like it's been running in circles and now it's running out of steam and I'm exhausted.

Comment: I am beginning to think that this has no simple recursion solution :) backtracking itself can be done quite easily, but the requirement for real time progression leaves it a bit too complex.

Comment: found a bit crude solution :) polishing will be done tomorrow

Comment: Polishing would be great but honestly you might be the greatest person ever. It does exactly what I want. It repaints some back to white but it still leaves a path showing the shortest way to goal no matter where it is. Thank you so much. You’re amazing. I can’t thank you enough for this help.

Comment: No problem. I it was actually fun to get back to recursion :)